# Topical corticosteroids on penis vasoconstriction

Tags: topical-cream-gel, penis, corticosteroids, erection, vasoconstriction

If you apply topical corticosteroids to the penis (due to medical indication), can these cause local vasoconstriction and can the vasoconstriction be bad for sexual health (erections)? Or does the vasoconstriction not affect erections because of where it happens?